# Microsoft Graph API - Getting Planner Task - Permission Error

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I am using Microsoft Graph Explorer to test some get requests (e.g: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/planner/tasks) and it works. 
I created the URL in the python script. The script contains also other get requests and they work like: get the Username und their ID. 
But when i check the output, i get this error: "You do not have the permissions ...".
I´ll put the full error below.

```
{'error': {'code': 'UnknownError', 'message': '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>\r\n<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>\r\n<style type="text/css">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id="content">\r\n <div class="content-container"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n', 'innerError': {'request-id': '01b084bb-fd48-4cf3-b83b-dd1641a0e889', 'date': '2020-06-09T22:33:18'}}}
```

I checked my permissions. [My Permissions in Microsoft Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIs6e.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planneruser-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

The only permissions i need are Group.Read.All and Group.Read.Write.All, which i already got. And i am Admin btw.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Application permissions are now supported.

Outdated Reply:

> Your request is failing because the token supplied is an app-only
> token.  Planner currently doesn't support application permissions, you
> need to use delegated credentials.
>
> Application permissions are announced:
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-updates-to-the-planner-api-in-microsoft-graph/